# Set parent version to exact version

Tags: java, maven

I'd like to update parent pom in a number of projects to a specific version. So I need to set the correct version, a.b.c, and can't use an algorithm to deduce the right one.

I thought mvn versions: should have a method like

```
mvn versions:setParentVersion 1.2.3
```

but it doesn't exist.

Is there a good way to perform this?

To expand a little:

We have several projects:

- /projects/parent-bom/pom.xml (contains common libraries)
- /projects/main-project/pom.xml (uses parent-bom)
- /projects/main-project/sub/pom.xml (submodule to main)
- /projects/support-project/pom.xml (uses parent-bom)

I now (for reasons...) need to say that parent-bom is of version (jira-1234) and then to the other projects to use the jira-1234-version of the parent bom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=[1.2.3]`

Comment: I ran the command but the  <parent> <version>-tag was untouched.

Comment: Turns out that the answer is correct, if your get the right version of org.codehaus.mojo:versions.... 

I ended up using the following command: 
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.16.2:update parent -DparentVersion=a.b.c -DskipResolution.